# i2c LCD Backlight

Tags: python, i2c, lcd

I have an LCD display that has a backlight (since when I plug it in it lights up). However, using the code below I cant get it to turn on. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import smbus
import time

# Set up I2C LCD
I2C_ADDR = 0x27  # I2C address of the LCD module
LCD_WIDTH = 16   # Maximum characters per line

LCD_CHR = 1  # Mode - Sending data
LCD_CMD = 0  # Mode - Sending command

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80  # LCD RAM address for the 1st line
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0  # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line

ENABLE = 0b00000100  # Enable bit
BACKLIGHT_ON = 0x08  # Backlight on command
BACKLIGHT_OFF = 0x00  # Backlight off command

# Timing constants
E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)  # Rev 2 Pi uses 1

def lcd_init():
    # Initialize display
    lcd_byte(0x33, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_byte(0x32, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_byte(0x06, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_byte(0x0C, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_byte(0x28, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)
    
    # turn on backlight
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR,BACKLIGHT_ON)
    

    


def lcd_byte(bits, mode):
    # Send byte to data pins
    # bits = data
    # mode = 1 for data, 0 for command

    bits_high = mode | (bits & 0xF0) | ENABLE
    bits_low = mode | ((bits << 4) & 0xF0) | ENABLE

    # High bits
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_high)
    lcd_toggle_enable(bits_high)

    # Low bits
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_low)
    lcd_toggle_enable(bits_low)


def lcd_toggle_enable(bits):
    # Toggle enable
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, (bits | ENABLE))
    time.sleep(E_PULSE)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, (bits & ~ENABLE))
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)


def lcd_string(message, line):
    # Send string to display

    message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH, " ")

    lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

    for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
        lcd_byte(ord(message[i]), LCD_CHR)
```

Comment: I don't see any executable code

Comment: it's because it is part of a larger code that consists of around 300 lines. hence i uploaded only this section and its required libraries as this is most likely where the problem is

Comment: If you know what the problem is why are you asking?

Comment: What is this LCD display? How do you know the backlight is i2c controlled? What does its spec say?

Comment: i bought this as the kit (Freenove Kit) it was in, was recommended by my school. this is my first time working with lcd's and i did my best to scour resources online and adapt them to fit my project which involves displaying the number of available parking spaces and when a button is pressed once, this decreases by 1 and if it is pressed again the same variable is increased by 1.

Comment: you said that the backlight already works ... `when I plug it in it lights up` ... what are you trying to do really? ... how are you trying to do it?

Comment: Basically, the lcd i am using has 4 connections: ground, 5V, SDA, SCL. Whenever, I unplug the 5V cable and reconnect it, the back light turns on. But when I run the code that contains the snippet above that initializes the LCD, the backlight turns off.

Comment: Any explanatory information should be edited in to your question.  I am not going to read comments to understand your question.

Comment: @Amanda_Sterling why couldn't you say that in the first place? ... not describing what happens is counterproductive ... please use the `edit` button to update your question

Comment: figure out if any line in `lcd_init()` causes it